# Strange behaviour when animating between two circular UIBezierPaths

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

**The Problem**
I am creating an exploding rings effect. I'm using multiple `CAShapeLayer`'s and creating a `UIBezierPath` for each layer. When the view is initialised, all the layers have a path with width `0`. When an action is triggered, the rings animate to a larger path.

As seen in the demo below, the right hand edge of each layer is slower to animate than the remainder of each circular layer.

**Demo**
[image: Video]

**Code**

Drawing the layers:

```
func draw(inView view: UIView) -> CAShapeLayer {

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    // size.width defaults to 0
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center, radius: size.width / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(360.0).toRadians(), clockwise: true)

    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath
    shapeLayer.frame = view.frame

    return shapeLayer
}
```

Updating the layers

```
func updateAnimated(updatedOpacity: CGFloat, updatedSize: CGSize, duration: CGFloat) {

    let updatePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center, radius: updatedSize.width / 2,
                                  startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(360).toRadians(), clockwise: true)

    let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    pathAnimation.fromValue = layer.path // the current path (initially with width 0)
    pathAnimation.toValue = updatePath.CGPath


    let opacityAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    opacityAnimation.fromValue = self.opacity
    opacityAnimation.toValue = updatedOpacity


    let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
    animationGroup.animations = [pathAnimation, opacityAnimation]
    animationGroup.duration = Double(duration)
    animationGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animationGroup.removedOnCompletion = false

    layer.addAnimation(animationGroup, forKey: "shape_update")

    ... update variables ...

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid starting with a path width of 0. It is very difficult to scale from 0 and tiny floating-point errors magnify. Values very close to zero are not very continuous in floating point (hmmm.... I guess that actually is a little like the real universe). Try starting with larger values and see how close to zero you can go safely.

Comment: Setting the initial value of the width to 1 instead of 0 seems to have solved it, thanks for your help!